# Controller method's result is not accessible on view in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to print a controller method's result on view but it is giving me an error:
Undefined variable: $states. Can someone help me to point out what is wrong in my code?

**Model code:**

```
public function state_names() {
    $query =  $this->db->select('name')
                    ->get('place')
                    ->where('parent','India');
    $query->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public function state_names() {
    $st['states'] = $this->place_model->state_names();
    if ($this->form_validation->run('resource_signup') == TRUE) {
        if (isset($st['states']) && $st['states']->num_rows() > 0) {
            $this->load->view('/web/resource_signup',$st);
        }   
    }
    return array();
}
```

**View code:**

```
<?php foreach ($states as $state) {
  echo $state->name;
}
```

Comment: in your controller, after calling model function state_names, print this to see if you are getting data from db or not.

Comment: I dont know, why you are validating. Is there any special reason to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your model you are running query twice - for each method get(). You should run it once:

```
public function state_names() {
    $query =  $this->db->select('name')
                    ->where('parent','India')
                    ->get('place');
    return $query->result();
}
```

In your controller you can't check *num_rows()* because there are results - not full response from database.

```
public function state_names() {
    $st['states'] = $this->place_model->state_names();
    if ($this->form_validation->run('resource_signup') == TRUE) {
        if (isset($st['states'])) {
            $this->load->view('/web/resource_signup',$st);
        }   
    }
    return array();
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but still facing same issue on view: Undefined variable: states

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
public function state_names() {
        $this->db->select('name')
        $this->db->get('place')
        $this->db->where('parent','India');
        $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: ```echo $state->name;``` this statement is not needed any array. Its a Standard Class Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is 2 place First in Model and second in controller

> if (isset($st['states']) && $st['states']->num_rows() > 0)
>
> and Model

1. Model Solution

   `public function state_names() {
       $query =  $this->db->select('name')
                       ->where('parent','India')
                       ->get('place');
       // $query->db->get();
       if($query->num_rows() > 0){
           return $query->result();
       }
   }`

N.B [ Here Where will be first and get will be last its good practice ];

Controller Solution :

```
public function state_names() {
    $st['states'] = $this->place_model->state_names();

    if ($this->form_validation->run('resource_signup') == TRUE) {
        if (isset($st['states']) ) {
            $this->load->view('/web/resource_signup',$st);
        }   
    }
    return array();
}`
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this solution but, still facing same error on view: Undefined variable: states

Comment: Problem is your form validation. For Testing purpose just use this 

`if (isset($st['states']) ) {
            $this->load->view('/web/resource_signup',$st);
        }'